# Google Docs =Filter() will randomly show "N/A" till I erase the function and paste it back in

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I've been having a consistent issue where every =Filter() function on my spreadsheets will stop working, they will all just display "N/A" "No Matches Found In Filter Evaluation". I am filtering data from the same sheet, not importing it.

I have to copy the function, delete it, hit enter to apply the changes to the cell, paste it back in and hit enter to apply the function again. After that it will work as expected.

This happens with no rhyme or reason, and affects all worksheets in my document. How do I prevent this? Is there any way to automatically fix this without copy/pasting my functions dozens of times on a regular basis?

Edit: Function Example

```
=FILTER(Organize!F2:K1000, Organize!D2:D1000 = B6, Organize!C2:C1000 =A6, (Organize!E2:E1000 = "Doug") + (Organize!E2:E1000 = "Rach Owes Doug")+ (Organize!E2:E1000 = "Both")+ (Organize!E2:E1000 = "Rach Owes Doug Split"))
```

This shows as "N/A" "No Matches Found In Filter Evaluation" till I delete and paste it back in.

Comment: Added a function example, if that's what you needed.